# Update Active Directory User Password using LDAP and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ldap

I'm using LDAP with SQL Server to retrieve some records from Active Directory.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT          
    sAMAccountName,
    givenname,
    displayName,
    telephonenumber,
    mobile,
    userAccountControl,
    userPassword, unicodePwd, dBCSPwd,
    accountExpires, 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY (ADSI, 'SELECT sAMAccountName
                            , givenname
                            , displayName
                            , telephonenumber
                            , mobile
                            , userAccountControl
                            , userPassword
                            , unicodePwd
                            , dBCSPwd
                            , accountExpires
                       FROM  ''LDAP://myserver.com''
                       WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' 
                       AND objectClass = ''user''
                       AND givenname = ''username''
') AS tblADSI
```

First strange thing I noted, that all password columns (`userPassword`, `unicodePwd`, `dBCSPwd`) are returning NULL, but all users have passwords.

But what I really need is to change Active Directory users password using a SQL Server command with LDAP. How do I do that?

Comment: I doubt you could do this - the SQL Server interface to AD was always only read-only - and it's been deprecated for a while now - I'd recommend you find another way to do this

Comment: The password isn't stored anyway, only its hash, and I doubt you would get that over ADSI. That field is probably just legacy

Comment: @marc_s Whats would you suggest? We have experts in C# (asp.net and asp.net core) here in our team, do you have any reference/link of a documentation to this in any language or command line? I just need to set a new password and unlock users.

Comment: Check out the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) namespace available in C# - for .NET 4.x as well as .NET Core / .NET 5 - the [`UserPrincipal` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) has methods to change / set the password on users